# INSERT INTO... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... IF

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck on this one INSERT INTO for my school assignment.

```
INSERT INTO leaderboardeasy VALUES("Patrik", 15.44, 2021-04-24) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IF(15.44 < Ido) Ido=15.44, Datum=2021-04-24
```

The 15.44 is a PHP variable.Basically I want insert into the table, if it not exists, and if it exists, and if the PHP variable(in this case 15.44 is smaller than the corresponding row(Ido) ) then I want to update the Ido, and Datum(current date) of the duplicate key.

What is the problem with my query?

Comment: Have you defined an unique index? What is the problem with the query?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with: `IF(15.44 < Ido) Ido=15.44, Datum=2021-04-24 `?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something along the lines of this: `... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Ido = IF(15.44 < Ido, 15.44, Ido), Datum = IF(15.44 < Ido, '2021-04-24', Datum)`

Comment: @NikolayShindarov Ido currently for "Patrik" is set at 16.44, and if the PHP variable (15.44 in this case) is smaller than Ido (which is 16.44) then I want to update Ido and Datum

Comment: @kmoser Yes that is exactly what I was trying to do, but for some reason, it inserts a new "Patrik" into my table with the new value.

Comment: @pacuhh What is your primary key?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly your goal for the if statement is if the `IF` condition is met to update `ido` and `datum` to the given values, and otherwise not to update them and keep them intact. If this is the case:

```
INSERT INTO leaderboardeasy 
VALUES("Patrik", 15.44, '2021-04-24') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`Ido` = CASE
   WHEN (15.44 < `Ido`) THEN 15.44
   ELSE `Ido`
END,
`Datum` = CASE
   WHEN (15.44 < `Ido`) THEN '2021-04-24'
   ELSE `Datum`
END
```

Comment: I don't know if it's something with PHPMyAdmin, but If I Run this exact same code, then I end up with having multiple instances of "Patrik", with different values, instead of updating the one where "Patrik" is. [Something like this](https://imgur.com/a/jxpfR8h)

Comment: Is the `name` (or whatever the first column is called) a unique index? If it's not, you must make it such. Otherwise the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ` would not trigger.

Comment: In theory it should be these are the commands for my table:
CREATE TABLE `leaderboardeasy` (
  `Nev` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
  `Ido` double NOT NULL,
  `Datum` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `leaderboardeasy` (`Nev`, `Ido`, `Datum`) VALUES
('asd', 17.88, '0000-00-00'),
('Karakai', 22.47, '2021-04-24'),
('lol', 18.94, '2021-03-24'),
('nice', 8.57, '2021-03-24'),
('Patrik', 15.44, '2021-04-24'),
('TrisztÃ¡n', 23.82, '2021-03-24');

ALTER TABLE `leaderboardeasy`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`Nev`(100));
COMMIT;

Comment: If it was a unique key it wouldn't let you add a duplicate record regardless. You must look into this.

Answer (score 0):

you have a basic problem that dates have to be in single qiotes.
the if statement is not like mysql work,.

But i don't know if that reaöly  makes what you want.

Because this would only run when Patrick is a primary key or a unique

```
INSERT INTO leaderboardeasy VALUES("Patrik", 15.44, '2021-04-24') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Ido = IF(15.44 < Ido,15.44,Ido) , Datum=VALUES(Datum)
```

Better is a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_leaderboardeasy_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON leaderboardeasy FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   
    IF NEW.Ido > 15.44 THEN
        SET NEW.Ido = 15.44;
    END IF; 

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```